# UIImageView image and UIButton not showing

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

Given that Visual Studio no longer supports the storyboard visually and that I'm not a fan of XCode, I'm exploring ways to generate a View (screen) programmatically.  I've managed to put a View controller together with a storyboard and I'm able to get to a screen at runtime.  The problem I'm having is that 2 items refuse to display anywhere on the screen no matter what I do.

First issue, how do I determine what the title bar height/width and location is?  I'm just guessing right now and I do manage to get subviews to appear below the title bar as opposed to under it, I still would like to be able to know how to determine programmatically it's locatioon and it's size.  That would be a big help to start.

Second issue is that no mater what I do I cannot get an image into a UIImageView and display on the resulting screen.

Third and last issue, I cannot get the button to appear either, no idea why, but it just doesn't.

I'll admit, constraints are a total mystery to me so I use Cirrious FluentLayouts to manage the screen layout and this may also be a source of my problem, please bear with me as I may be ignorant of how some things work.  I have working c# code that I use for chatroom purposes with android and I've ported it to this iOS project and now I'm trying to construct a screen to manipulate/display the data.

My Code:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        var height = this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Bounds.Height;
        var width = this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Bounds.Width;

        UIImageView banner = new UIImageView();
        banner.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Banner2,jpg");
        // I've also tried .FromFile, .FromResource ... no luck
        banner.Frame = new RectangleF(100, 0, 414, 73);
        UILabel lblTitle = new UILabel();
        lblTitle.Text = theSelectedTeam + " " + "Chat Room";
        UILabel txtChatMessages = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, 340, width, View.Bounds.Height - 340));
        txtChatMessages.Text = "Messages will appear here";
        UITextField txtSendingTextMessage = new UITextField(new CGRect(0, width, width, 100));
        txtSendingTextMessage.Placeholder = "Enter Message To Send Here";
        UIButton btnSendText = new UIButton();
        btnSendText.Frame = new Rectangle(0,0,414,73);
        btnSendText.SetTitle("Send Text", UIControlState.Normal);

        View.Add(banner);
        View.Add(lblTitle);
        View.Add(txtChatMessages);
        View.Add(txtSendingTextMessage);
        View.Add(btnSendText);

        View.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

        View.AddConstraints(
            banner.AtTopOf(View, 100),
            banner.AtRightOf(View, 0),
            banner.AtLeftOf(View, 0),
            lblTitle.Below(banner, 5),
            lblTitle.WithSameCenterX(banner),
            txtChatMessages.Below(lblTitle, 10),
            txtSendingTextMessage.Below(txtChatMessages, 10),
            btnSendText.Below(txtSendingTextMessage, 10),
            btnSendText.WithSameCenterX(txtSendingTextMessage)
        );
    }
```

For the banner, I've set the image as a "BundleResource" in the project, but nothing is ever displayed.  I've tried `UIImage..FromFile` and `UIImage..FromResource` , but again, nothing.  No errors, no banner.  I'm reasonably sure that I'm setting the image view below the title bar because I see the other components (except for the button) and there IS a space where the banner should be.  Now the button never appears anywhere, also no matter what I do.

This is the storyboard entry as it appears in the Main.storyboard:

```
    <!--Chat Room-->
    <scene sceneID="FbH-rf-ojS">
        <objects>
            <viewController restorationIdentifier="Messenger" storyboardIdentifier="Messenger" title="Chat Room" interactionActivityTrackingBaseName="Messenger" id="Gsp-eR-wUZ" customClass="Messenger" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="9oL-te-Yse"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="lGH-Kz-h0z"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="B19-qP-8K7">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="393" height="852"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                </view>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="i1W-0e-jAe" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="4743" y="31"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
```

I'm (apparently) very confused as to how things work with iOS screens (storyboards) and could use some help.  I do get the screen at runtime and three of the controls (subviews) are displayed in more or less the correct position, just not the banner and the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was painful.  No reason to wonder why I despise all things Apple.

Just for the record I use Visual Studios 2022 v17.5.5 (lastest version as of this writing) on Windows 11.

iOS apps store images (files/data?) a little differently than android, I'm not surprised, just baffled as to why this isn't documented anywhere.  It's not enough to know the filename, you need to fully qualify where it located and you don't do that with simple forward slashes in the string such as `Resources/drawable`, nope, one has to use a period and qualify it with the app assembly name as defined in the Visual Studios project properties under `Project->App_Name Properties->Application`.  Also, set the image as an embedded resource by expanding the `Resources/drawable`folder in the Visual Studios solution explorer window, highlight the image (file?), in the properties window select the build action and set it to `Embedded Resource`. So, to get the image to display, my code is now:

```
        UIImageView banner = new UIImageView();
        banner.Image = UIImage.FromResource(null, "MYTEST_APP.Resources.drawable.Banner2.jpg");
        banner.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, 414, 73);
        banner.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
```

The notable change being `banner.Image = UIImage.FromResource(null, "MYTEST_APP.Resources.drawable.Banner2.jpg");`.  No where in anything I read ANYWHERE is this noted, not in the Apple documentation or Visual Studio documentation.  Frustrating, to say the least.

The button issue turned out to be an easy one, the button was actually there, one just couldn't see it as I had not set the text color ... duh .... apparently `black` is not the default, transparent apparently is.  Again, no where in anything I've read is this mentioned.  For the record, my code is now:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        var height = this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Bounds.Height;
        var width = this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Bounds.Width;
        UIImageView banner = new UIImageView();
        banner.Image = UIImage.FromResource(null, "MYTEST_APP.Resources.drawable.Banner2.jpg");
        banner.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, 414, 73);
        banner.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
        UILabel lblTitle = new UILabel();
        lblTitle.Text = theSelectedTeam + " " + "Chat Room";
        UILabel txtChatMessages = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, 340, width, View.Bounds.Height - 340));
        txtChatMessages.Text = "Messages will appear here";
        UITextField txtSendingTextMessage = new UITextField(new CGRect(0, width, width, 100));
        txtSendingTextMessage.Placeholder = "Enter Message To Send Here";

        UIButton btnSendText = new UIButton();
        CGRect ScreenBounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
        float buttonWidth = (float)ScreenBounds.Width / 4;
        btnSendText.Frame = new RectangleF(0f, 0f, buttonWidth, 50f);
        btnSendText.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
        btnSendText.SetTitle("Send Text", UIControlState.Normal);

        View.Add(banner);
        View.Add(lblTitle);
        View.Add(txtChatMessages);
        View.Add(txtSendingTextMessage);
        View.Add(btnSendText);

        View.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

        View.AddConstraints(
            banner.AtTopOf(View, 100), // A margin of 100 sets the image below the title bar, but there is some space between it and the title bar, so some work is needed here
            banner.AtRightOf(View, 0),
            banner.AtLeftOf(View, 0),
            lblTitle.Below(banner, 5),
            lblTitle.WithSameCenterX(banner),
            txtChatMessages.Below(lblTitle, 10),
            txtSendingTextMessage.Below(txtChatMessages, 10),
            btnSendText.Below(txtSendingTextMessage, 10),
            btnSendText.WithSameCenterX(txtSendingTextMessage)
        );

        btnSendText.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
          // execute send text function here
        };
    }
```

One will note the line `btnSendText.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);`.  The button is now visible and functional, I obviously need to change a few things to display a fully functional "chat room" screen, but now at least I'm getting things to show up on the screen.  Half the battle, now on to the other half.  I suspect that I'll figure out a solution to exactly where the title bar is by trial and error, but at least I know I can programmatically create iOS screens and do not have to rely on XCode, which I despise.